# How to use Pandas within Python to create a Fiscal Year Column?

Tags: python, pandas, date, range, fiscal

I have a code with python that cleans a .csv up before I append it to another data set. It is missing a couple columns so I have been trying to figure how to use Pandas to add the column and fill the rows.

I currently have a column *DiscoveredDate* in a format of 10/1/2017 12:49.

What I'm trying to do is take that column and anything from the date range 10/1/2016-10/1/2017 have a column *FedFY* have its row filled with 2017 and like wise for 2018.

Below is my current script minus a few different column cleanups.

```
    import os
    import re
    import pandas as pd
    import Tkinter
    import numpy as np

    outpath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "CSV Altered")

    # TK asks user what file to assimilate
    from Tkinter import Tk
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

    Tk().withdraw()
    filepath = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file

    #Filepath is acknowledged and disseminated with the following totally human protocols
    filenames = os.path.basename(filepath)

    filename = [filenames]

    for f in filename:
    name = f
    df = pd.read_csv(f)

        # Make Longitude values negative if they aren't already.
        df['Longitude'] = - df['Longitude'].abs()

        # Add Federal Fiscal Year Field (FedFY)
        df['FedFY'] = df['DiscoveredDate']
        df['FedFY'] = df['FedFY'].replace({df['FedFY'].date_range(10/1/2016 1:00,10/1/2017 1:00): "2017",df['FedFY'].date_range(10/1/2017 1:00, 10/1/2018 1:00): "2018"})
```

I also tried this but figured I was completely fudging it up.

```
 for rows in df['FedFY']:
    if rows = df['FedFY'].date_range(10/1/2016 1:00, 10/1/2017 1:00):
        then df['FedFY'] =  df['FedFY'].replace({rows : "2017"})
    elif df['FedFY'] =  df['FedFY'].replace({rows : "2018"})
```

How should I go about this efficiently? Is it just my syntax messing me up? Or do I have it all wrong?

[Edited for clarity in title and throughout.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerned *only* with these two FYs, you can compare your date directly to the start/end dates:

```
df["FedFY"] = np.where((df.DiscoveredDate < pd.to_datetime("10/1/2017")) &\
                       (df.DiscoveredDate > pd.to_datetime("10/1/2016")), 
                       2017, 2018)
```

Any date before 10/1/2016 will be labeled incorrectly! (You can fix this by adding another `np.where`).

Make sure that the start/end dates are correctly included or not included (change `<` and/or `>` to `<=` and `>=`, if necessary).

Comment: You can _accept_ the answer if you like it. Accepting an answer increases your rep, too.

Answer (score 3):

Ok thanks to DyZ I am making progress; however, I figured out a much simpler way to do so, that figures all years.

Building on his np.where, I:

```
 From datetime import datetime

 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DiscoveredDate'])
 df['CalendarYear'] = df['Date'].dt.year
 df['Month'] = df.Date.dt.month
 c = pd.to_numeric(df['CalendarYear'])
```

And here is the magic line.

```
df['FedFY'] = np.where(df['Month'] >= 10, c+1, c)
```

To Mop up I added a line to get it back into date time format from numeric.

```
df['FedFY'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['FedFY'], format = '%Y')).dt.year
```

This is what really crossed the bridge for me [Create a column based off a conditional with pandas.](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_create_column_using_conditional/)

Edit: Forgot to mention to import date time for .dt stuff